# Eclipse maven project with multiple main method

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have Maven project on eclipse, and the project has multiple main entry point within different packages. How can i create .jar correctly so I can choose which main method to run?
I tried creating jar using maven install, but when I run it cannot find or load the main class, and I am running .jar like this.

```
java jar myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.project.Main
```

I also tried this andstill same error

```
java -cp myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.project.Main
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>edu.cpp.cs499</groupId>
  <artifactId>Netflix-MapReduce</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Netflix-MapReduce</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Can you add your maven file?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can paste the `pom.xml` and describe how do you create `.jar` now.

Comment: i added the pom.xml above. I build .jar using eclipse run as -> maven install

Comment: `java -jar myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` should work for a defined Main class. Else `java -cp myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.project.Main` should work fine. Please share the logs for the error.